# Postfix - Block email from non-existent local addresses

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, spam

My question is very similar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/31278/block-mails-with-local-from-addresses-from-unauthenticated-senders-using-courier) one, but for postfix.

We keep getting emails from addresses like "accounting@example.com" delivered to our actual "@example.com" addresses. From my google research, I understand it might not be practical to verify the email originated from our IP or VPN (Although this would be ideal, so if you can think of a way to do this, let me know), but in most of these cases the sender address (ex. "accounting") is not a valid account.

I imagine there must be a way to make sure that a local account exists before delivering the message.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add [`reject_unlisted_sender`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender) to your [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions).

Without a little planning this will also reject mail from root@hostname.example.com as well, so keep that in mind.

---

> **smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender**
>   Request that the Postfix SMTP server rejects mail from unknown sender
>   addresses. This can slow down an explosion of forged
>   mail from worms or viruses.
>
> An address is always considered "known" when it matches a virtual(5)
>   alias or a canonical(5) mapping.
>
> The sender domain matches $mydestination, $inet_interfaces or
>   $proxy_interfaces, but the sender is not listed in
>   $local_recipient_maps, and $local_recipient_maps is not null.
>
> - The sender domain matches $virtual_alias_domains but the sender is not listed in $virtual_alias_maps.
> - The sender domain matches $virtual_mailbox_domains but the sender is not listed in    $virtual_mailbox_maps, and $virtual_mailbox_maps
>     is not null.
> - The sender domain matches $relay_domains but the sender is not listed in $relay_recipient_maps, and $relay_recipient_maps is not
>     null.
>
>   This feature is available in Postfix 2.1 and later.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to add SPF to your domain:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework